# SQL Query ORDER BY on column not on select on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

The issue I am facing is the following, I have 2 tables joined and I want to pull 2 columns (1 of each), but I want to order by a third column on one of the tables, So far I have been unsuccesful, this is the query I have tried but its not working.

```
SELECT
    [Months].[Month] AS 'Name',
    SUM(ISNULL([Documents].[Balance],0)) AS 'Value'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Months].[Month],
        SUM(ISNULL([Documents].[Balance],0)),
        MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    FROM
        [Documents]
    LEFT JOIN [Months] ON
        [Months].[MonthNumber] = MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    GROUP BY
        [Months].[Month], MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    ORDER BY
        MONTH([Documents].[Date]) ASC
)
```

Any help with this issue?

Comment: Did you try moving the ORDER BY clause outside the sub query? SQL Server must have complained about it.

Comment: The only `ORDER BY` clause that affects the order of rows in the output result set is one specified on the outermost query. Any other location you use `ORDER BY`, it's to help to define some other feature (`TOP`, `OFFSET ... FETCH` or a window function) and doesn't have any *defined* influence over the order in which results are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the derived table / sub query.

```
    SELECT 
        [Months].[Month] AS 'Name',
        SUM(ISNULL([Documents].[Balance],0)) AS 'Value',
        MONTH([Documents].[Date]) AS 'Mth'
    FROM
        [Documents]
    LEFT JOIN [Months] ON
        [Months].[MonthNumber] = MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    GROUP BY
        [Months].[Month], MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    ORDER BY
        Mth ASC
```

if you only required the Name & Value column as result, remove the `MONTH([Documents].[Date])` from the `SELECT` and change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY MONTH([Documents].[Date])`

Comment: see my last comment in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why you need subquery here ? you can `JOIN` & use `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT m.[Month], SUM(ISNULL(d.[Balance], 0))
FROM [Documents] d LEFT JOIN 
     [Months] m 
     ON m.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(d.[Date])
GROUP BY m.[Month], MONTH(d.[Date])
ORDER BY MONTH(d.[Date]);
```

However, column in `order by` clause which is not present with `SELECT` statement it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I dont want the column to show on the select result

Comment: @V.Benavides. . . I don't have that column in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use order by column in select list

```
SELECT 
        [Months].[Month] AS 'Name',
        SUM(ISNULL([Documents].[Balance],0)) AS 'Value',
        MONTH([Documents].[Date]) AS  dcosdate
    FROM
        [Documents]
    LEFT JOIN [Months] ON
        [Months].[MonthNumber] = MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    GROUP BY
        [Months].[Month], MONTH([Documents].[Date])
    ORDER BY
        MONTH([Documents].[Date])
```